# NSIS: Get return code of ExecShell

Tags: nsis

I have to use `ExecShell` because my main programm has only user permissions and the called exe file inside this programm needs admin permissions.

```
 RequestExecutionLevel user  

 ExecShell "open" "file.exe" SW_HIDE
```

I want get the return code, I tried to `pop $0, pop $1`, but I get always zero. Also if the file wasn't succesful.
I believe that `pop $0` doesnt't wait for the `ExecShell` command, but I can't use `ExecWait` because of the needed admin permissions. How could I get the true return code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecShell` does not report a error code because it does not wait for the process.

If you want the exit code you have to call [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) manually:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh

!ifndef SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS
!define SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS 0x00000040
!endif

Section
StrCpy $1 "Calc.exe" ; File to execute
System::Call '*(&l4, i ${SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS}, p$HWNDPARENT, p0, tr1, p0, p0, p5, p0, p0, p0, p0, p0, p0, p)p.r1'
System::Call 'SHELL32::ShellExecuteEx(t)i.r0 (pr1)' ; (t) is a hint for A/W detection
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Call '*$1(i, i, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p.r0)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::WaitForSingleObject(p r0, i ${INFINITE})'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetExitCodeProcess(p r0 s,*i.r0)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::CloseHandle(p s)'
    DetailPrint ExitCode=$0
${EndIf}
System::Free $1
SectionEnd
```